# Price ui text field: how to allow user to enter only one decimal dot in to the text field for price like 283.99

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, nspredicate

I have tried with this code as follow

this helps me to allow user to enter **only numbers and dot (decimal point)**

But the **problem is user can allow n number of decimals in this method.**

I want to allow only one decimal

and only two digits after the decima

**like 123.00 , 123423432353.99** 
**but not like 123.4.4 , 123.12345, 123...23**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


      if (string.length == 0) {
            return YES;
      }
      NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];
      for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                  return YES;
            }
      }
      UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Invalid input" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [av show];
      return NO;

}
```

How to allow user to enter only one decimal the text field that too allow only two digits after the decimal

thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't let your question answered ! Do followup either you found a solution or not. Helpful for the entire community, for those who are looking for answers and those who are solving problems.

Answer (score 5):

> **Best practices** Use RegularExpressions whenever you have to perform any string format validation like **Email,Phone Number,Currency etc.**

This surely will solve your problem. Here sample code below:

**First create instance of NSRegularExpression**

```
NSError error;
NSRegularExpression * regExp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"^\\d{0,10}(([.]\\d{1,2})|([.]))?$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

**then use in your relevant method:**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range    replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString * existingText = textField.text;
    NSString * completeText = [existingText stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",string];

    if ([regExp numberOfMatchesInString:completeText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [completeText length])]) 
    {
        if ([completeText isEqualToString:@"."])
        [textField insertText:@"0"];
        return YES;
    }
    else
     return NO;
 }
```

Use and let me know if it works.

Comment: You need to consider the range parameter when calculating the completeText.

Comment: I think i am considering...Its working fine.#

Comment: NSString * completeText = [existingText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one...It may helps you and please implement your functionality.This code for only 2 digit after "."

```
 NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([sep count]>=2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
    return YES;
```